# The Three Coffins

Tags: family

Two mothers and two daughters were in a multi car accident. They were all pronounced dead at the scene. All the bodies have been moved to the local mortuary. There are only three coffins. No one is sharing a coffin and none are left out. How is it possible?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: Very low quality

Comment: Here is the bigger puzzle... which of the mothers was herself not somebody's daughter?

Comment: @Michael - the motherF***er who did it. :) i dont know if this is the real answer. i never seen this part of the question.

Comment: @xnor - [PEBCAK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two mothers and two daughters but in

> three different generations.

One of them is

> both a mother and a daughter.

Comment: can you use spoiler tags

Comment: let's give this guy a Reversal while we're at it...

Answer (score 1):

There are:

> 4 people in total.
> Three of them wished to be buried in a coffin upon death, but one of them wanted to be cremated upon death.  Cremated remains are not placed in a coffin.

"None are left out" of the local mortuary.

Comment: I assumed "*...and none are left out*" meant that all the bodies were in coffins.

Comment: Answers that are entirely spoilers are frowned upon.

Comment: @Geobits Never assume with a puzzle.  Could mean "none are left out" of the mortuary.